# Accessing Motorola MC9500 motion sensor programmatically?

Tags: c#, windows-mobile-6.5, motion-detection, motorola-emdk

I am currently working on a windows mobile application for `Motorola MC9500` which has `Windows Mobile 6.5`.
I have tried Symbol's `EMDK` library to access inbuilt motion sensor of the device without any luck.

The EMDK for .NET v2.7 has `Symbol.Sensor` class library in it which is supposed to be accessing all inbuilt sensors, but I have no idea how to work with it.

`Symbol.Sensor.SensorManager manager = new Symbol.Sensor.SensorManager();`

I get a `MissingMethodException` exception here, saying...
 "Can't find `PInvoke DLL` `SensorsAPI.dll`."

What should I do to access the motion sensor using C# ?

If there is any other alternative, please tell.

Comment: On my opinion the only way is to follow Motorola's way through its libs. Generally i don't like Symbol (unfortunately i meet them often) but when i use symbol api e.x. to open photo and close wedge, i do it with dll import.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @kostasch. , can you help me out here please, about, why I'm getting this error here.
I usually work on C++ , so I am not familiar with DLLImport either.
I don't know how to use it.
It would be great if you could show me a small code sample, because when I use `DllImport` it shows error.

Comment: So if i understand well you need a dllimport example?

Comment: Would it work ?
Because when I searched manually, I did not find `SensorsAPI.dll`.
Still, an example would be great. 
Thanks

Comment: I have posted a dll import example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this is the conclusion I reached so far...
The sensors of Motorola MC9500 is not programmatically accessible.

Answer (score 2):

I will post a dllImport example as continue of comments of @HemendraSharma. The above code is written for mobile devices and is used to change system hour.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace changeHour
{   

public class cDateTime  
{       

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]       
    private struct SystemTime
    {           
        public ushort uYear;            
        public ushort uMonth;           
        public ushort uDayOfWeek;           
        public ushort uDay;         
        public ushort uHour;            
        public ushort uMinute;          
        public ushort uSecond;          
        public ushort uMilliseconds;            

        public SystemTime(
            ushort uYear, 
            ushort uMonth, 
            ushort uDay, 
            ushort uHour, 
            ushort uMinute, 
            ushort uSecond)
        {               
            this.uYear = uYear;             
            this.uMonth = uMonth;               
            this.uDayOfWeek = 0;                
            this.uDay = uDay;               
            this.uHour = uHour;             
            this.uMinute = uMinute;             
            this.uSecond = uSecond;             
            this.uMilliseconds = 0;         
        }       
    }       

    [DllImport("Coredll.dll")]          
    private static extern bool SetLocalTime(ref SystemTime st);

           [DllImport("Coredll.dll")]           
           private static extern uint SetSystemTime(ref SystemTime st);     



    public static bool SetDateTime(
        int iYear, 
        int iMonth, 
        int iDay, 
        int iHour, 
        int iMinute, 
        int iSecond)        
           {            
        SystemTime st = 
            new SystemTime
            (
            Convert.ToUInt16(iYear), 
            Convert.ToUInt16(iMonth), 
            Convert.ToUInt16(iDay), 
            Convert.ToUInt16(iHour), 
            Convert.ToUInt16(iMinute), 
            Convert.ToUInt16(iSecond)
            );          
        return SetLocalTime(ref st);        
    }

    public static uint SetDateTimeSystem(
        int iYear,
        int iMonth,
        int iDay,
        int iHour,
        int iMinute,
        int iSecond)
    {
        SystemTime st =
            new SystemTime
            (
            Convert.ToUInt16(iYear),
            Convert.ToUInt16(iMonth),
            Convert.ToUInt16(iDay),
            Convert.ToUInt16(iHour),
            Convert.ToUInt16(iMinute),
            Convert.ToUInt16(iSecond)
            );
        return SetSystemTime(ref st);
    }       


    public static bool SetDateTime(DateTime dt)     
    {           
        return SetDateTime
            (
            dt.Year, 
            dt.Month, 
            dt.Day, 
            dt.Hour, 
            dt.Minute, 
            dt.Second
            );      
    }       


    public static bool SetDate(int iYear, int iMonth, int iDay)
    {           
        DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;         
        return SetDateTime(
            iYear, 
            iMonth, 
            iDay, 
            dt.Hour, 
            dt.Minute, 
            dt.Second);     
    }       

    public static bool SetDate(DateTime date)       
    {           DateTime time = DateTime.Now;           
        return SetDateTime(
            date.Year, 
            date.Month, 
            date.Day, 
            time.Hour, 
            time.Minute, 
            time.Second);       
    }       

    public static bool SetTime(int iHour, int iMinute, int iSecond)
    {           
        DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;         
        return SetDateTime(
            dt.Year, 
            dt.Month, 
            dt.Day, 
            iHour, 
            iMinute, 
            iSecond);       
    }       


    public static bool SetTime(DateTime time)       
    {           
        DateTime date = DateTime.Now;           
        return SetDateTime(
            date.Year, 
            date.Month, 
            date.Day, 
            time.Hour, 
            time.Minute, 
            time.Second);       
    }       

}
 }
```

Comment: Ok, I just tried this, I don't know if its right or not.
`[DllImport("SensorsAPI.dll")]

private static extern Symbol.Sensor.SensorManager SensorManager();

private Symbol.Sensor.SensorManager Manager()

{

    return new Symbol.Sensor.SensorManager();

}`

Still I am getting the same error.

"Can't find PInvoke DLL SensorsAPI.dll."

Comment: Do you have any example from Motorola?

Comment: Do you have this dll in your windows folder?

Comment: Yes, there is a sample included in the EMDK from Symbol. When I tried to run this sample. It also gave me the exact same error.
I was wondering, can it be the problem in .NETCF ?

Comment: Check  SensorsAPI.dll where is located?

Comment: I don't think that motorola publish an example for .NETCF and the .NETCF have problem with that.

Comment: It does not exist, either on device or PC. I tried to search for it, but could not get any help for that too.

Comment: Try to find a SensorsAPI.tlb file.

Comment: I use DataWedgeApi.tlb which is somthing like yours.

Comment: There is no SensorsAPI.tlb file either. Please tell, where can I find it, and what does it do ? How to use it if I find it ?

Comment: Check to symbol's example. This will add as a reference in your project and you will not need dllimport. You will have all the methods you need. I remind you that was in my case, that motorola gave me that tlb. In any case you will need SensorsAPI.dll or SensorsAPI.tlb. I download DataWedgeApi.tlb from se setup of symbol.

Comment: Has somewhere in Symbol's project some file that's staring with "SensorsAPI"?

Comment: If not, you have do download from motorola's site some sdk.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32073/discussion-between-hemendra-sharma-and-kostas-ch)

Comment: @HemendraSharma Sorry but i can't now because in my work firewall do not let me.

Comment: I really cannot find anything else than EMDK to download and install on PC or device. :(

Comment: Generaly i think that you must go that way. I will be at stackoverflow in 5-6 hours. If you r in we may have a discussion.

Comment: EMDK may be compiled from MOtorola for other processor. for other devices. The best you have to do is to ask local vendor or motorola generaly.

Comment: @ HemendraSharma Did you find it?

Comment: No @kostasch , not yet. Did you find anything helpful ?